# simple recursion function to add to 10

Tags: c++

```
int count(int i)
{
    //base case
    if(i==10){
        return 0;
    }

    //recursive case
    if(i!=10){
        return 1 + count(i++);
    }
}

int main()
{
    cout << count(0) << endl;
}
```

I am trying to count to ten but it segment faults at line 6. When I run gdb This error 0x000000000040081e in count (i=) at recursiveCount.cpp:6.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Check the value of `i` on each call to `count`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It only looks like that because of the redundant _if_ statement.  All logical control paths still return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

```
count(++i);
```

Instead of this:

```
count(i++);
```

++i uses what is called the prefix increment operator, which increments i before any other operations take place. i++, on the other hand, utilizes the postfix increment operation, which takes place after another operation (in this case, a function call) takes place. In other words, using the postfix operator makes it so that the function is called with the same value every time.

Also,

instead of doing this:

```
//base case
if(i==10){
    return 0;
}

//recursive case
if(i!=10){
    return 1 + count(i++);
}
```

you can do this:

```
//base case
if(i==10){
    return 0;
}

//recursive case
else {
    return 1 + count(i++);
}
```

Using `else`, other than making the code clearer, also uses less of the CPU, since a second comparison of values (as in, the if arguments) doesn't occur.

Comment: Why not just `return count(i + 1);`? This is still overly confusing for such a simple task.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Using the prefix operator tells the compiler to use the more efficient INC instruction, which only needs to take one register as input as opposed to the ADD instruction, which takes one register as input and modifies AX.

Comment: That's total nonsense on so many levels I don't even know where to begin. First, where is it written that C++ compiles to a CPU that has instructions called "INC" and "ADD"? What rule says one will be more efficient than the other for all CPUs? And what kind of idiotic compiler couldn't make this obvious micro-optimization if it was one on that particular platform?